# Is there any way for mypy to support instance checking from within a function?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, static-typing, isinstance

Is there any way for `mypy` to support instance checking from *within* a function?

I am aware of the `isinstance` support for [complex type checking](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#complex-type-tests). I have the following module as minimal example for illustration purposes:

```
from typing import Any, Union

def is_str(argument: Any) -> bool:
    return True if isinstance(argument, str) else False

def my_string_function(input_str: str):
    print(input_str)

def my_string_and_int_function(argument: Union[str, int]):

    if is_str(argument):
        my_string_function(argument)

    if isinstance(argument, str):
        my_string_function(argument)
```

Now if I run mypy I get the following error for the *first* (not the second!) function call of `my_string_function` from within the `my_string_and_int_function`:

> error: Argument 1 to "my_string_function" has incompatible type "Union[str, int]"; expected "str"

Maybe this is more appropriate for the mypy issue tracker but as I am unsure I thought of posting it here first.

Comment: Not currently. It's on the roadmap https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5206 though.

Comment: Thanks for the info! This feature would greatly improve the usability!